# h:selectOneMenu value is always null when submitting the form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, form-submit, selectonemenu

I have a `h:selectOneMenu` which served me with no issues in the past but for some reason the value in `searchResults.selectedCategories` is always null when submitting the form.

The widget is inside a form. The backing bean has `selectedCategories` as a private String with accessor methods. I tried cleaning the project, closing down Eclipse, and republishing it to Tomcat. Nothing works. Any idea why?

This is the widget:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="categoriesBoxSimple" value="#{searchResults.selectedCategories}" >
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Category 1" itemValue="283331" />                    
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Category 2" itemValue="281" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Category 3" itemValue="1115"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: "Nothing works" is not a proper description of your actual problem. - Look for validation errors, check if the setter method is called.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the form isn't nested and the ajax action -if any- is also executing/processing the menu? Nonetheless, your problem must be one of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked/2120183#2120183

Comment: @BalusC for testing I added  <f:ajax listener="#{searchResults.testMethod('test!')}"/> to the widget and now the value catches. But when submitting the form it doesn't. I have other similar widgets at the same place on the page and they work as expected.

Comment: Just create a MCVE based on the code then.

Comment: I guess I'm just going to use it with the f:ajax from my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
`Add`
<f:ajax listener="#{yourBean.ajaxChangeValue}" />
to h:selectOneMenu

<h:selectOneMenu value = "#{yourBean.numberValue}"> 
<f:selectItem itemValue="One" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="Two" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="Three" />
<f:ajax listener="#{yourBean.ajaxChangeValue}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

YourBean.java
public void ajaxChangeValue(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {    
// do something
}

//getter and setter of numberValue
```

Comment: Why? That is a (most likely not needed) workaround for a non clear problem (and already described by the OP). So it is effectively not an 'answer') and your answer is not very good formatted. Please check and edit